# Hybrid Auth Codeigniter Says" Error authenticating user." after i host to the server.in local server is working perfectly

Tags: php, codeigniter, hybridauth

Hybrid Auth Codeigniter Says" Error authenticating user." after i host to the server.in local server is working perfectly.

I configured it in local server.before configure it i made vhost.
Now in local server it is working perfectly.not in the server.

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case it was json extension in php. i installed the `json` and `curl` (it uses json and curl) extension on my server and and it stopped saying `Error authenticating user`

For `curl` on ubuntu use

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

And for `json` use

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Hope it helps others

Comment: actually in my case that is not the issue.there is a log file that records every log.in the server there wasn't permission for that.that is why i got this error.after i gave the permission it started working ..

Answer (score 2):

I tracked it down to the fact that the file /application/logs/hybridauth.log did not have proper write permissions. After solving this, the login started working fine.